# Difference between Unix timestamp convert in JS and QTDatetime?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

Converting unix timestamp "1441028773999" in JS (in QML):

```
console.log(new Date(1441028773999)) //result is Mon Aug 31 10:46:13 2015 GMT-0300 (RIGHT RESPONSE)
```

Converting in QT CPP class:

```
QDateTime dt = QDateTime::fromTime_t(1441028773999);
QString textdate = dt.toString( Qt::TextDate ); //result is "3/7/40 7:43 AM" (WRONG RESPONSE)
```

How I can convert this timestamp in QT Class with a right response like a JS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch`.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html#fromMSecsSinceEpoch